# Altair automatic save chart as svg using selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, altair

I am trying to produce few charts in a loop and save them automatically.

I am working on Windows, using Chrome.

I have been following [the documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/saving_charts.html#png-and-svg-format) on how to save a chart in svg.

I downloaded the appropriate ChromeDriver for my Chrome version.
`gdf` is my geodataframe and everything works smoothly and I can generate and manually save charts.

Below is the piece of code I am trying to run:

```
#Chromedriver for headless run and chart automatic save
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathtochromedriver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

#loop
for group in gdf['Group Name'].unique():
    map_1km_json = json.loads(gdf[gdf['Group Name']==group].to_json())
    map_1km_data = alt.Data(values=map_1km_json['features'])
    data_1km_geojson = alt.InlineData(values=map_1km, format=alt.DataFormat(property='features',type='json'))
    domain=[1,2]
    range_=['#b0d247','#007bd1']
    choro1_5 = alt.Chart(map_1km_data).mark_geoshape().encode(
        alt.Color('properties.Cat2:O', scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_),title = "Havvandsstigning"),
        #alt.Color('properties.Cat2', type='quantitative', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='plasma'),title = "Havvandsstigning")
        tooltip = ['properties.dd_km1:N','properties.Cat2:N']
    ).properties(
    width=1100,
    height=800
    )
    (background + choro1_5).save("{}.svg".format(bank))
driver.quit()
```

Running the code opens an empty new chrome pane (in the background) that looks like this:
[image: chromepane]

But the code returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    776         except:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
   1179             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-6067387e4b2f> in <module>
     19     height=800
     20     )
---> 21     (background + choro1_5).save("{}.svg".format(bank))
     22 driver.quit()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v3\api.py in save(self, fp, format, override_data_transformer, scale_factor, vegalite_version, vega_version, vegaembed_version, **kwargs)
    478         if override_data_transformer:
    479             with data_transformers.disable_max_rows():
--> 480                 result = save(**kwds)
    481         else:
    482             result = save(**kwds)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\save.py in save(chart, fp, vega_version, vegaembed_version, format, mode, vegalite_version, embed_options, json_kwds, webdriver, scale_factor, **kwargs)
    102                                         vegaembed_version=vegaembed_version,
    103                                         webdriver=webdriver,
--> 104                                         scale_factor=scale_factor, **kwargs)
    105         if format == 'png':
    106             write_file_or_filename(fp, mimebundle['image/png'], mode='wb')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\mimebundle.py in spec_to_mimebundle(spec, format, mode, vega_version, vegaembed_version, vegalite_version, **kwargs)
     54                               vega_version=vega_version,
     55                               vegaembed_version=vegaembed_version,
---> 56                               vegalite_version=vegalite_version, **kwargs)
     57         if format == 'png':
     58             render = base64.b64decode(render.split(',', 1)[1].encode())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\headless.py in compile_spec(spec, format, mode, vega_version, vegaembed_version, vegalite_version, scale_factor, driver_timeout, webdriver)
    152             webdriver_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    153 
--> 154     driver = webdriver_class(options=webdriver_options)
    155 
    156     try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     71             service_args=service_args,
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 
     75         try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
---> 83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     84                 )
     85             elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: None of the above solutions (which by the way are the same) fixed my issue. I already give an absolute path to `chromedriver.exe` and adding `executable_path=r` before the path doesn't work either.

Comment: When I ran into this problem it was because I hadn't run `brew cask install chromedriver` which installed the executable into a place on my PATH. I believe that when you save with `altair` it looks for the `chromedriver` executable -- separate from python. Have you tried adding `pathtochromedriver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe` to your PATH instead of importing it with `selenium`?